# Is there a way to force .NET GC to shuffle managed objects?

Tags: c#, .net, unsafe

When testing `unsafe` C# code I would sometimes need the GC to move managed objects around between specific instructions, to test, if any unmanaged pointer incorrectly points to a non-pinned managed object.

Is there any way to write tests for this kind of bugs or should we just never make bugs in an `unsafe` code?

Comment: It would be hard if not impossible to force the GC to change the address of every managed object, just for testing purposes. The reason unmanaged code is difficult to debug and prone to memory issues is precisely because it doesn't have a garbage collector that tracks these things -- if it was possible to test these things reliably there'd be little need for a GC in the first place. You can use the [Managed Debugging Assistants](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/diagnosing-errors-with-managed-debugging-assistants) for a little more help.

Comment: it feels like such a tantalizing idea, but I believe the answer is "no, there is no such thing inbuilt"

Comment: Note that even if the GC offered such a function, you wouldn't be able to use it to reliably detect problems on the unmanaged side, since you have no way of knowing which unmanaged pointers (if any) are supposed to point to a managed object, and even if they do, whether they are still "alive" or not (just having the pointer value somewhere is not an error, only if it's dereferenced). This is the main problem a GC solves.

Comment: @JeroenMostert well, *yes*, but if you *were* able to use GC to crawl the alive *managed* objects, and copy / offset all non-pinned into another pane of memory (essentially using the same approach that compaction uses) it should force doom for anything that was not safe; however, I'm pretty sure nothing exists to do this in the GC

Comment: @MarcGravell: if by "force doom" you mean "trigger undefined behavior unless there was also some way to trigger an access violation for all those addresses", then yes. :P Otherwise, unfortunately, "doom" would not necessarily be reliable enough to eliminate false negatives. (I suppose we could copy `0xDEADBEEF` or zeros everywhere to hopefully trigger some obvious problem, but even this is hardly reliable.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert idea was that after GC would move managed objects (simulating compaction) we could compare values of data where unmanaged pointers point to, with expected values, to test, if there is any mismatch.

Comment: @JeroenMostert agreed; the reality that some bits may be pinned means we can't just release all the existing old pages